# Code Not Working For Old Users After Website Migration

Tags: laravel, collections, dns

We have a website vehicle search page and over a week ago we migrated to a new hosting provider.

All old users who are revisting and some select users don't see any results on our search however when utilising dd on the collection of products it shows the correct count however the list of results are not part of the collection.

If we use incognito or flush our dns, chrome cache and local cache we can see the results properly.

I can provide the code pieces in question if required, however wondering if anyone has had this issue before.

Thanks

We have done the following;

- Flushed the cache and cookie via code in the controller
- localstorage refresh with jquery
- localsession refresh with jquery
- updated all versions on style sheets and javascript to refresh them
- ran composer update to see if that helps
- Cleared every inch of cache via laravel commands on the server ,application cache, views, routes, configs
- new key
- change cache clearance in htaccess
- changed from Public to no-store in htaccess

The following 3 worked however not ideal as we can't utilise this on customers machines;

- Flushed chrome cache via browser
- Flushed dns via cmd line
- Icognito

This is the part of code that retrieves and makes up the collection;

```
$products = $this->product->search($data, $page->id, 24, $type, $userlatLon);
```

This function is the following;

```
public function search($data, $pageId, $productsPerPage, $type, $userlatLon)
    {
        if($pageId == 1536){
          unset($data['images']);
        }
        $sortArray = self::sortArray();
        $avaiableFilters = self::avaliableFiltersArray();
        $types = self::determineTypeFromGivenInt($type);
        $select = 'products.url, products.id, products.registration_date, products.created_at as in_stock_date, products.location_code, products.type, products.special_order, products.price, products.sale_price, products.make, products.model,
        products.derivative, products.mileage, products.live_until, products.model_year, products.year, products.times_viewed_in_the_last_week, products.transmission, products.tax_cost, products.fuel_type, our_title, our_description, i.our_src_440, f.term, f.first_payment, f.id as finance_id,
         no_of_regular_payments, monthy_payments, final_payment, cash_price, cash_deposit, engine_size_formatted, total_deposit, amount_of_credit, total_charge_for_credit, total_amount_payable, products.plus_vat, products.attention_grabber,
          apr, l.friendly_name as location_name, l.url as location_url, l.gmaps_url as gmaps, l.address_1, l.town, l.city, l.postcode, l.telephone, if(sale_price > 0 AND sale_price < (price - 100) , 1 , 0) as reduced';

        !!!MORE QUERYING IS HERE!!!


        if ($type == 4) {
            $products = $products->has('pdfRecord')->groupBy('products.make', 'products.model')->paginate($productsPerPage, ['products.url']);
        } else {
            $products = $products->groupBy('products.id')->paginate($productsPerPage, ['products.url']);
        }

        return $products;

    }
```

The expected results should be all products showing like a normal user sees.

However the collection returns 648 results but non of the results are part of the collection

Comment: Look like the problem come from some data stored on the user side. Have you tried to change the cache key prefix into config\cache.php and the session cookie name into config\session.php

I'm not sure if it will solve it, but it should force the user to store the data in a new place, so older data will not be use.

Comment: @ElieMorin thanks for the suggestion, I have done this and we're still experiencing the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: just by curiosity, have you done ```php artisan clear-compiled``` after editing config file?

Comment: @ElieMorin Hi, I have just done the clear-compiled and this still hasn't worked.

Comment: After doing more testing on an affected users computer I can see that the query is returning no results what so ever from my database. Even if I do a fresh query (Products::all()) it returns 0 items in the result set. I have also looked at the query connection details and these are all referencing the new tables/database and the new ip address.

Comment: I really don't know. I think you could try to do something like this: \Log::info(\DB::getDatabaseName()); and look into Logs to be sure the user try to connect to the right one. Maybe something somewhere change the database the user try to reach. If Products::all() return 0 it could be so many thing.